# Add Hyphen to Every Character after the first two characters

Tags: java

I need to insert a hyphen to every char after the first two character.

i.e.    `String text = "spiderman";`

should become:    `sp-i-d-e-r-m-a-n`.

this is what i got so far

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print ("Enter A Text: ");
    String text = input.nextLine();
    char dash;
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr<text.length(); ctr++)
    {
        dash = text.charAt(ctr);
        System.out.print (dash+"-");
    }
```

Comment: Update your code also in question...which one you tried.

Comment: Try yourself `text.charAt(0)` means `'s'` Simple clue: first find the string length `int str = text.length()` and loop it `for(int i = 0; i < str_length; i++) {` if index is greater than 1 append - to character else left as it is. `if( i > 1) { temp += "-" + text.charAt(i);` else `temp += text.charAt(i);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Run below code and you will get expected string.

    String text = "spiderman";
    String resultant = "";
    if(text.length() <= 2)
        resultant = text;
    else
        resultant = ""+ text.charAt(0) + text.charAt(1);
    for(int i=2;i<text.length();i++)
    {
        resultant += "-" + text.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println("resultant - " + resultant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of the string:

```
String.length()
```

You will get the characters of the string using indexes:

[image]

http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/java/data/getchar.html

> The first integer argument specifies the index of the first character.
>   The second integer argument is the index of the last character -1

[image]

**Now, use string builder based on the character that is after the second index to insert hie fens after every other character. Put the string in a for loop to loop through every character, and use string builder's method `append`.**

From the docs:

> The principal operations on a StringBuilder are the append and insert
>   methods, which are overloaded so as to accept data of any type. Each
>   effectively converts a given datum to a string and then appends or
>   inserts the characters of that string to the string builder.

Answer (score 0):

Rakesh's answer works perfectly but if the string length is quite big, i suggest using StringBuilder otherwise your string literal pool might grow explosively

```
String text = "spiderman";
StringBuilder resultant = new StringBuilder();

if(text.length() <= 2) {
    return text;
}
else
   resultant.append(text.charAt(0)).append(text.charAt(1));
for(int i=2;i<text.length();i++)
{
    resultant.append("-").append(text.charAt(i));
}
return resultant.toString();
```